# Exactly 1 Solution with Pivot in Every Column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that pivot in every column means at least 1 solution, but is it possible to have exactly 1 solution for pivot in every column for a non-square coefficient matrix?

Comment: I don't fully understand the context. Are you thinking of systems of linear equations, expressed in forms like $\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1&0&2\\0&1&3\end{array}\right)$? This is a system of two equations in two variables, the left-hand side has pivots in both columns, and the system has exactly one solution.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about systems of linear equations. I forgot to clarify, I meant specifically coefficient matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the matrix is wider than it is tall, then solutions are never unique. But if it is taller than it is wide, if all columns have a pivot, then when solutions exist, they are unique, but there need not be solutions at all. Take 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
There are no solutions to 
$$A\textbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} 0  \\ 0  \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
But if a solution to $A\textbf{x} = \textbf{b}$ exists, then it is unique.